# Is there any react-native apps can be found in App Store?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want spread react-native in my company.  I need a few examples to persuade my colleagues, but I can hardly find any . Can any one help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/showcase.html
- http://www.reactnative.com/built-with-react-native/

First two hits when [googling "react native showcase"](http://www.google.com/search?q=react+native+showcase).